# UITabBar custom icon color is not getting shown

Tags: ios, ios7, uitabbar

I am using UITabBar in iOS app. I have set images to UITabBar items. Code is-

```
self.mainTabBar.delegate = self;
mainTabBar.tintColor = nil;

[[mainTabBar.items objectAtIndex:0] setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_1.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_1.png"]];
[[mainTabBar.items objectAtIndex:1] setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_2.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_2.png"]];
[[mainTabBar.items objectAtIndex:2] setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_3.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_3.png"]];
[[mainTabBar.items objectAtIndex:3] setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_4.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_4.png"]];
[[mainTabBar.items objectAtIndex:4] setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_5.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_5.png"]];
```

This is code for tab bar. It is showing like -
 [image]
Actual icon image is like (colors are like this)- 
[image]

How can I show actual colors of icon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use it like this if you are using iOS 8.

```
UIImage *image1 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"message"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

tabBarItem1.image = image1;
tabBarItem1.selectedImage = image11;
```

Here is the source : [UITabBarItem/selectedImage](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarItem_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITabBarItem/selectedImage)

> By default, the actual selected image is automatically created from
>   the alpha values in the source image. To prevent system coloring,
>   provide images with UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `UITabBarItem`s from inside their view controllers. Do not set them directly.

For example:

```
UITableViewController *searchTableCon = [[UITableViewController alloc]init];
UINavigationController *searchNavCon = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:searchTableCon];

searchTableCon.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Search"
                                                    image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Search"]
                                            selectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Search"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do following thing for this.

```
UIImage * selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"selected_image.png"];
selectedImage =    [selectedImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
viewCtrl.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" image:selectedImage selectedImage:selectedImage];
```